# How to format this txt file in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file that contains more than 5000 lines.  Every line looks like this:

`http://domain.com/xyz.html`

Every line is different from the other lines in only the xyz part.  It look like this:

     `http://domain.com/xyz.html
     http://domain.com/eee.html
     http://domain.com/sss.html
     http://domain.com/ddd.html
     .......
     etc`

I need to change all lines in bulk to became like this:

    `http://domain.com/xyz/xyz.html
    http://domain.com/eee/eee.html
    http://domain.com/sss/sss.html
    http://domain.com/ddd/ddd.html
    ......
    etc`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

CTRL + F
Replace
Tick the "regex" button (regular expression)

Search for `http:\/\/domain\.com\/(.*?)\.html`
Replace with `http:\/\/domain\.com\/\1\/\1\.html`

Comment: Thank you.This is work perfect.